# Akka Actors - Change default behavior of messages arriving in actors

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-actor

Is it possible in [Akka Actors](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/actors.html) to install some kind of 'hook' that allows you to run a self-defined piece of code every time a new message arrives in an actor? Note, this is not the moment when the actor starts handling the message with `receive` but the moment when the message arrives in the actor and is put into its mailbox. Also note that I want to change the default behavior, not just the behavior for one individual actor. Ideally I would change this behavior at just one spot throughout my code and it would affect all actors automatically, or by only requiring 1-2 lines of code in each file/actor (such as an import statement).

For example, using this hook it should be possible to log a message every time it arrives or to calculate and print the fibonacci of the size of the mailbox before/after insertion.

Comment: If logging and monitoring of `mailbox` are the main requirements consider `Kamon`. Otherwise use a custom `MailBox` as mentioned in the last topic of the link in @LeviRamsey's post. A simple implementation of a custom mailbox is given there. Try it out, then block the code at different locations like `enqueue`, `dequeue`, and `receive` of an actor and see the effect of it.

Comment: The issue with defining a custom mailbox seems to be that this locks in my or other's choice for a mailbox (the one I implemented). I would like to keep the code as it is, with actors being able to choose their type of mailbox, but to all of them I would like to add my own code. It's comparable with the principle of `extend` I think.

Comment: Adding a custom mailbox or extending the mailbox have the same pitfalls as it can block if you are not careful. BTW, both can be configured in one place and the `ActorSystem` can use that.

Answer (score 1):

If you control the spawning of the actor (or are willing to use this mailbox as the default for actors which don't specifically set a mailbox), you can use a custom mailbox.  See [the docs for details](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/mailboxes.html).

Comment: I've edited the question with some extra requirements that were not clear in the original question. Would this solution still apply?

Comment: Follow the link Levi provided, as it does explain that, yes, you can change the default mailbox. You can even find some code to implement this if you Google "Akka mailbox logging gist". However, one thing I would caution is that just because you can add this code doesn't mean you should. You are introducing contention (and potentially blocking behavior) into your enqueueing. If you just are trying to monitor the size of your mailboxes there are MUCH better ways to do it than this.